# SQL query which should yield something for a non-existing element

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

So, the table looks like this

```
doc_id is the customer device
st1 and st2 are some states of this device
datetime is the date of a transition between them
```

[image: sql table]

What I need to do is to produce an output table that will tell me when was the first occurrence of the `2` state AND the last occurrence of the `6` state for every `doc_id`

The thing is that not every `doc_id` has got every state.
The result should look like this:
[image: sql output]

And I've got no idea as to how to get this.
So, first of all, what I did was `union all`'ed every state for a `doc_id`, so that I could find the first occurrence of the `2` state and last occurrence for the `6` state.
The thing is that with aggregate functions you're not getting anything if, say, this generalised `state_id` has never ever happened to a `doc_id`
I can get something like:

```
1 01.01.2014
2 05.01.2014
```

and

```
2 10.01.2014
3 13.01.2014
```

in separate tables, but I have no idea as to how should I combine these outputs to get it the way it should be.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select doc_id,
       min(datetime) filter (where st1 = 2) as s2_firststate2,
       max(datetime) filter (where st2 = 6) as s2_laststate6
from t
group by doc_id;
```

Your column names are confusing; they suggest that you only care about `st2`.  However the results suggest that you care about both.  These are transitions, so the above should work, but you might also want:

```
       min(datetime) filter (where 2 in (st1, st2)) as s2_firststate2,
       max(datetime) filter (where 6 in (st1, st2)) as s2_laststate6
```

Comment: @Simullacra . . . `filter` is SQL standard syntax, but Postgres is one of the few databases that support it.